# Phrase: give pause

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

What exactly does the phrase give (sb.) pause mean?

Is it just a simple shortening of the following?:

> **give pause to someone (or give someone pause for thought)**
>
> cause someone to think carefully or hesitate before doing something: the sight of these gives any would-be attacker pause for thought. -*Oxford Dictionary of English*

Sounds *wrong* but it must be a phrase of some sort, right?

Answer (score 1):

About 500 years ago, Shakespeare wrote in Hamlet (3:1): “For in that sleep of death what dreams may come ... Must give us pause.”

And although it *seems* like there must be more to it, it just means that surprise or doubt caused a hesitation before one reacts.

Most commonly, it is used in a self-referential manner.  After all, you know when something takes you aback, but you're never sure whether you've given someone else pause, or they only appeared to hesitate because they just weren't paying attention.